# Tensorflow Federated in a hierarchical fashion

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow-federated

I'm trying to use tensorflow federated to simulate a federated learning algorithm in a hierarchical topology. For what I've read, only a few strategies are implemented (such as tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process), which relies on a single aggregation server. Is there any way to have networks that are more complex than the standard n-clients 1-server?

Answer (score 0):

TFF has native support for intermediate aggregation; a binary, for example, which runs code analogous to that [implemented for testing here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/tests/remote_runtime_test_utils.py#L63) and serves analogously to the [remote executor service](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/tools/runtime/remote_executor_service.py) could connect to workers and aggregate in a hierarchical manner.

You may, however, mean something more general than this.